# Setting up Voice Commands in my VB.net application

Tags: vb.net, voice, sapi

I wanted to put voice command options into my application.  I read stuff online about grammers and SAPI but I can't seem to figure out how to actually use it in my VB.net applications.  Does anybody know of any good guides or tutorials for me to use to get started on the subject?

Thanks :)

Comment: [This](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/110148-sapi-53/) dreamincode topic seems to have a good code sample.

Comment: @M.Babcock  Please post that as an answer.  That tutorial worked wonders :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a pretty good tutorial with code sample [here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/110148-sapi-53/) that provides a fairly thorough walkthrough of the APIs and discusses the differences between SAPI 5.1 and 5.3.